# Button can't click() on javascript if it has multiple button in one div/list

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have problem that Button can't click() on javascript if it has multiple button in one div/list. In this case, "ADD" button doing nothing if i click it. But "Delete" button can. If i remove Delete function on js, add button work properly. What's wrong?

I have **HTML** like this

```html
<ul class="coll-list">
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
   
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And **JS function** :

```js
 var id ="";
 
 $('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-remove-coll', function(e) {
       id = $(this).data('id'); 
       
       // doing ajax thing
});

 $('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-add-coll', function(e) {
       id = $(this).data('id'); 
       
       // doing ajax thing
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens because the second `$('.coll-list').off('click')` remove **ALL** `on('click')` event you have set before (i.e. on click on `.btn-remove-coll`, in this case).

You can try to change your `off('click').on('click')` order in your page and you'll see that will change the working button (or Delete or Add).

**Here only remove button works**

```js
 
$('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-add-coll', function(e) {
  alert("add")
});


 $('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-remove-coll', function(e) {
  alert("remove")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="coll-list">
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
   
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**And here add button only**

```js
 $('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-remove-coll', function(e) {
  alert("remove")
});
 
$('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-add-coll', function(e) {
  alert("add")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="coll-list">
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
   
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

2 possible solution to make both buttons work are:

1. Simply remove `off('click')`
2. Combine your 2 clicks in 1 `on('click')`

```js
$('.coll-list').off('click').on('click','.btn-add-coll, .btn-remove-coll', function(e) {

  if($(this).hasClass("btn-add-coll")){
    alert("add")
  } else {
    alert("remove")
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="coll-list">
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
   
   <li>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-remove-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Delete </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-coll" data-id='+data.id+'> Add </button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks @ReSedano!! i tried first solution and it worked!. i will try to use second solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.coll-list` from you JavaScript code with `.coll_list` because that is the class of you `ul` HTML tag.

**Edit**
It seems that it is impossible for some reason to have click functions for two different divs in the same `<li>` tag. I'd sugges you to change the HTML markup a bit, and use the `<div>` tag instead of `<ul>`. Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/592987](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/592987)

Comment: yep, it's typo when i write in that querstion. and that's not the problem.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible for some reason to have click functions for two different divs in the same <li> tag. I'd sugges you to change the HTML markup a bit, and use the <div> tag instead of <ul>.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/592987/